# How to get index of a named object inside an array

Tags: javascript, json

I have an array that contains multiple named objects. I already tried to use the javascript filter method and indexOf() but it returns -1.

Tried indexOf like so:

```
let idx = manifest.coffee.beans.indexOf("CB_2020_0005")
```

This is my manifest object

```
manifest: {
    userData: {},
    coffee: {
        beans: [
            "CB_2020_0001": {
                price: 2.5,
                amount: 5
            },
            "CB_2020_0005": {
                price: 3.3,
                amount: 10
            }
        ],
        instant: []
    }
}
```

How should I retrieve the index number of for example the second object "CB_2020_0005" inside of manifest.coffee.beans?

Comment: Your `beans` array is invalid. Are you sure it's not supposed to be an object?

Comment: Oh yes, I'm sorry it is supposed to be an object... But still I don't know how to get the index then. I'll try sourav's your answer now, thanks!

Comment: @DanteC if it is an object then what do you expect the result to give, since objects are not indexed like arrays?

Comment: Sorry my Object.keys earlier would have returned 0 or 1 instead. You can try this


let beans = [
        {
          "CB_2020_0001": {
            price: 2.5,
            amount: 5
          }
        },
        {
          "CB_2020_0005": {
            price: 3.3,
            amount: 10
          }
        }
      ]

beans.map((k,  index) => (Object.keys(k)[0] == 'CB_2020_0005') ? console.log(index): '')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Array.prototype.findIndex()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex):

```js
const obj = {
  manifest: {
    userData: {},
    coffee: {
      beans: [
        {
          "CB_2020_0001": {
            price: 2.5,
            amount: 5
          }
        },
        {
          "CB_2020_0005": {
            price: 3.3,
            amount: 10
          }
        }
      ],
      instant: []
    }
  }
};

const idx = obj.manifest.coffee.beans.findIndex(o => "CB_2020_0005" in o);
console.log(idx);
```

Comment: I think `.findIndex(o => "CB_2020_0005" in o)` would also work ;)